# How to map (Auto Mapping) in parent child relation in same table SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table in database with the data

But now requirement has been changed and I'm introducing a new column `ParentID` in the table

> Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EopsModule](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ModuleCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [IsDefaultModule] [bit] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EopsModule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

> Here is the output of the table

```
SELECT * FROM EopsModule

//Output

ID  ModuleCode  Description IsDefaultModule
1   EW001.00    Webshop standaard   1
2   EW001.01    Algemene functionaliteit en configuratie    1
3   EW001.01.1  Single- of Multishop    1
4   EW001.01.1.1    Optioneel: Multishop    1
5   EW001.01.2  Taal    1
6   EW001.01.2.1    Optioneel: Multi taal   1
7   EW001.02    Design & Lay-out    1
8   EW001.02.1  Standaard Lay-out wireframe / elementen 1
9   EW001.02.2  Responsive / Mobile Friendly    1
10  EW001.03    Content 1
11  EW001.03.1  Optioneel: Pagina artikelen (Website module)    1
12  EW001.03.1.1    Optioneel: Content header & footer (Website module) 1
13  EW001.03.2  Pagina Teksten  1
14  EW001.03.3  Optioneel: Slider (Website module)  1
15  EW001.03.4  Contact pagina  1
16  EW001.03.5  Optioneel: Bel me terug 1
17  EW001.03.6  Optioneel: FAQ (Website module) 1
18  EW001.03.7  Optioneel: Nieuws (Website module)  1
19  EW001.03.8  Navigatie menu  1
20  EW001.03.8.1    Assortiment navigatie uitklapmenu   1
21  EW001.03.9  Pagina Tracking Scripts 1
22  EW001.03.10 URL Re-directs  1
23  EW001.03.11 Cookie Notificatie / Privacy Policy 1
24  EW001.03.12 Error pagina’s  1
25  EW001.04    Login & Registratie 1
26  EW001.04.1  Inloggen    1
27  EW001.04.2  Inloggen met e-mailadres    1
28  EW001.04.3  Wachtwoord vergeten 1
29  EW001.04.4  Registreren 1
30  EW001.04.4.1    Goedkeuringsprincipe    1
31  EW001.04.4.2    Geen registratie    1
32  EW001.04.4.3    Open registratie    1
33  EW001.04.4.4    Optioneel: Gast-account 1
34  EW001.04.4.5    Registratieformulier    1
35  EW001.04.4.6    Registratie met ERP Data koppeling  1
36  EW001.05    Assortiment 1
37  EW001.05.1  Structuur   1
38  EW001.05.2  Product detail  1
39  EW001.05.3  Optioneel: Product relaties 1
40  EW001.05.4  Assortiment content (extra informatie)  1
41  EW001.05.5  Optioneel: Top Items    1
42  EW001.05.6  Optioneel: Recent bekeken producten 1
43  EW001.06    Zoeken  1
44  EW001.06.1  Standaard zoeken    1
45  EW001.06.2  Normaliseren    1
46  EW001.07    Bestellen   1
47  EW001.07.1  Winkelwagen 1
48  EW001.07.1.1    Optioneel: Snel bestellen   1
49  EW001.07.1.2    Optioneel: Orderregel opmerking 1
50  EW001.07.1.3    Optioneel: Winkelwagen beheer   1
51  EW001.07.2  Gegevens    1
52  EW001.07.3  Betaling    1
53  EW001.07.3.1    Op rekening 1
54  EW001.07.4  Controleren 1
55  EW001.07.4.1    Optioneel: Orderreferentie  1
```

After adding `ParentID` column in table, I need to map the primary `id` based on the `module code`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EopsModule] ADD [ParentID] INT NULL

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[EopsModule] WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
[BASE].[ModuleCode]
,   [BASE].[ParentCode]
,   [Parent].[ID] AS [ParentID]
FROM
(
SELECT
[EopsModule].[ModuleCode]
,   REPLACE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode], RIGHT( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode], CHARINDEX( '.', REVERSE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] ), 0 )), '' ) AS [ParentCode]
FROM [dbo].[EopsModule] WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [EopsModule].[ModuleCode]
) AS [BASE]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EopsModule] AS [Parent] WITH (NOLOCK)
ON [BASE].[ParentCode] = [Parent].[ModuleCode]
) AS [Parent]
ON [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] = [Parent].[ModuleCode]
```

> Above query Output

```
ID  ModuleCode  Description IsDefaultModule ParentID    ModuleCode  ParentCode  ParentID
167 EB001.00    Budgetshop  0   NULL    EB001.00    EB001   NULL
168 EB002.00    Webshop Management  0   NULL    EB002.00    EB002   NULL
169 EB003.00    Orders goedkeuren   0   NULL    EB003.00    EB003   NULL
170 EB004.00    Single sign-on  0   NULL    EB004.00    EB004   NULL
171 ED100.00    Dealer portaal  0   NULL    ED100.00    ED100   NULL
172 EM001.00    Maatwerk    0   NULL    EM001.00    EM001   NULL
1   EW001.00    Webshop standaard   1   NULL    EW001.00    EW001   NULL
2   EW001.01    Algemene functionaliteit en configuratie    1   NULL    EW001.01    EW001   NULL
3   EW001.01.1  Single- of Multishop    1   2   EW001.01.1  EW001.01    2
4   EW001.01.1.1    Optioneel: Multishop    1   2   EW001.01.1.1    EW001.01    2
5   EW001.01.2  Taal    1   2   EW001.01.2  EW001.01    2
6   EW001.01.2.1    Optioneel: Multi taal   1   5   EW001.01.2.1    EW001.01.2  5
7   EW001.02    Design & Lay-out    1   NULL    EW001.02    EW001   NULL
8   EW001.02.1  Standaard Lay-out wireframe / elementen 1   7   EW001.02.1  EW001.02    7
9   EW001.02.2  Responsive / Mobile Friendly    1   7   EW001.02.2  EW001.02    7
10  EW001.03    Content 1   NULL    EW001.03    EW001   NULL
11  EW001.03.1  Optioneel: Pagina artikelen (Website module)    1   10  EW001.03.1  EW001.03    10
12  EW001.03.1.1    Optioneel: Content header & footer (Website module) 1   10  EW001.03.1.1    EW001.03    10
22  EW001.03.10 URL Re-directs  1   10  EW001.03.10 EW001.03    10
23  EW001.03.11 Cookie Notificatie / Privacy Policy 1   10  EW001.03.11 EW001.03    10
24  EW001.03.12 Error pagina’s  1   10  EW001.03.12 EW001.03    10
13  EW001.03.2  Pagina Teksten  1   10  EW001.03.2  EW001.03    10
14  EW001.03.3  Optioneel: Slider (Website module)  1   10  EW001.03.3  EW001.03    10
15  EW001.03.4  Contact pagina  1   10  EW001.03.4  EW001.03    10
16  EW001.03.5  Optioneel: Bel me terug 1   10  EW001.03.5  EW001.03    10
17  EW001.03.6  Optioneel: FAQ (Website module) 1   10  EW001.03.6  EW001.03    10
18  EW001.03.7  Optioneel: Nieuws (Website module)  1   10  EW001.03.7  EW001.03    10
19  EW001.03.8  Navigatie menu  1   10  EW001.03.8  EW001.03    10
20  EW001.03.8.1    Assortiment navigatie uitklapmenu   1   19  EW001.03.8.1    EW001.03.8  19
21  EW001.03.9  Pagina Tracking Scripts 1   10  EW001.03.9  EW001.03    10
25  EW001.04    Login & Registratie 1   NULL    EW001.04    EW001   NULL
26  EW001.04.1  Inloggen    1   25  EW001.04.1  EW001.04    25
27  EW001.04.2  Inloggen met e-mailadres    1   25  EW001.04.2  EW001.04    25
28  EW001.04.3  Wachtwoord vergeten 1   25  EW001.04.3  EW001.04    25
29  EW001.04.4  Registreren 1   25  EW001.04.4  EW001.04    25
30  EW001.04.4.1    Goedkeuringsprincipe    1   29  EW001.04.4.1    EW001.04.4  29
31  EW001.04.4.2    Geen registratie    1   29  EW001.04.4.2    EW001.04.4  29
32  EW001.04.4.3    Open registratie    1   29  EW001.04.4.3    EW001.04.4  29
33  EW001.04.4.4    Optioneel: Gast-account 1   25  EW001.04.4.4    EW001.04    25
34  EW001.04.4.5    Registratieformulier    1   29  EW001.04.4.5    EW001.04.4  29
35  EW001.04.4.6    Registratie met ERP Data koppeling  1   29  EW001.04.4.6    EW001.04.4  29
36  EW001.05    Assortiment 1   NULL    EW001.05    EW001   NULL
37  EW001.05.1  Structuur   1   36  EW001.05.1  EW001.05    36
38  EW001.05.2  Product detail  1   36  EW001.05.2  EW001.05    36
39  EW001.05.3  Optioneel: Product relaties 1   36  EW001.05.3  EW001.05    36
40  EW001.05.4  Assortiment content (extra informatie)  1   36  EW001.05.4  EW001.05    36
41  EW001.05.5  Optioneel: Top Items    1   36  EW001.05.5  EW001.05    36
42  EW001.05.6  Optioneel: Recent bekeken producten 1   36  EW001.05.6  EW001.05    36
43  EW001.06    Zoeken  1   NULL    EW001.06    EW001   NULL
44  EW001.06.1  Standaard zoeken    1   43  EW001.06.1  EW001.06    43
45  EW001.06.2  Normaliseren    1   43  EW001.06.2  EW001.06    43
173 EW001.06.3  Optioneel: Zoeken op klant artikelnummer    1   43  EW001.06.3  EW001.06    43
46  EW001.07    Bestellen   1   NULL    EW001.07    EW001   NULL
47  EW001.07.1  Winkelwagen 1   46  EW001.07.1  EW001.07    46
48  EW001.07.1.1    Optioneel: Snel bestellen   1   46  EW001.07.1.1    EW001.07    46
49  EW001.07.1.2    Optioneel: Orderregel opmerking 1   47  EW001.07.1.2    EW001.07.1  47
50  EW001.07.1.3    Optioneel: Winkelwagen beheer   1   47  EW001.07.1.3    EW001.07.1  47
51  EW001.07.2  Gegevens    1   46  EW001.07.2  EW001.07    46
52  EW001.07.3  Betaling    1   46  EW001.07.3  EW001.07    46
53  EW001.07.3.1    Op rekening 1   52  EW001.07.3.1    EW001.07.3  52
54  EW001.07.4  Controleren 1   46  EW001.07.4  EW001.07    46
55  EW001.07.4.1    Optioneel: Orderreferentie  1   54  EW001.07.4.1    EW001.07.4  54
```

NOTE: Data has been mapped by using the above query, but i noticed there is a anomaly in the output i.e 
for every child module there is a parent id mapped , but in the case of third or fourth level of child there is a conflict b/w the parent module code and the child module code and at last the id for parent for a child is not correct please find the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding,

```
select p.id ParentId, p.ModuleCode ParentCode, c.ID, c.ModuleCode, c.Description 
from ##eopsmodule c 
left join ##eopsmodule p 
on c.modulecode like p.modulecode + '.' + '[1-9]' -- RE for only one digit. Not accept like '11', '24', '89'
```

And the Output is:

```
ParentId    ParentCode      ID  ModuleCode      Description 
NULL        NULL            1   EW001.00        Webshop standaard   
NULL        NULL            2   EW001.01        Algemene functionaliteit en configuratie
2           EW001.01        3   EW001.01.1      Single- of Multishop    
3           EW001.01.1      4   EW001.01.1.1    Optioneel: Multishop    
2           EW001.01        5   EW001.01.2      Taal    
5           EW001.01.2      6   EW001.01.2.1    Optioneel: Multi taal   
NULL        NULL            7   EW001.02        Design & Lay-out    
7           EW001.02        8   EW001.02.1      Standaard Lay-out wireframe / elementen 
7           EW001.02        9   EW001.02.2      Responsive / Mobile Friendly    
NULL        NULL            10  EW001.03        Content                             
10          EW001.03        11  EW001.03.1      Optioneel: Pagina artikelen (Website module)    
11          EW001.03.1      12  EW001.03.1.1    Optioneel: Content header & footer (Website module) 
10          EW001.03        13  EW001.03.2      Pagina Teksten
```

Comment: Yes it's working fine but in my DB I have 11,22,33 also, in this case, it does not work but thanks for showing another way :).

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution but a hint to explain what occurs

Your right/reverse substring sometimes returns value like '.2' (for example, but its true also for .1 .3 .4 ... and so on)

Then the replace command with that value occurs sometimes with a double match, for example with EW001.02.2.2

Then a bad parentCode is retained, for example EW001.02 instead of EW001.02.2

You might find another way to retrieve the good parent of each of your elements

**Edit**

Because it is only the last level of hierarchy that you need to match, you can use a suffix with your replace to get the right parent code :

```
REPLACE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] + '@', RIGHT( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode], CHARINDEX( '.', REVERSE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] ), 0 )) + '@', '' ) AS [ParentCode]
```

then the replace will only occurs once

Comment: thanks mate, but it still has the anomaly, of wrong parent id's.

Comment: Thanks, lot's it's working fine now but some data not reflected, not mapped `ParentID` based on the `ParentCode`  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me please change your query instead of

```
 REPLACE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode], RIGHT( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode], CHARINDEX( '.', REVERSE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] ), 0 )), '' ) AS [ParentCode]
```

try this as substring will return the exact value after '.'

```
SUBSTRING( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode], 0, ( LEN( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] ) 
- ( CHARINDEX( ''.'', REVERSE( [EopsModule].[ModuleCode] )) - 1 ))) 
AS [ParentCode]
```

> output :

[image]